# What are controllers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm bit confused.  Most of the widgets don't have a controller. Few have one ( camera, textfield ...)

What is the purpose of using a respective controller?

Why do we use it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In flutter, controllers are a means to give control to the parent widget over its child state.

The main selling point of controllers is that they remove the need of a `GlobalKey` to access the widget State. This, in turn, makes it harder to do anti-pattern stuff and increase performances.

Controllers also allow having a complex API without having thousands of callbacks on the widget. 
They also allow to *not* "lift the state up", as the State is still managed by the child.

Answer (score 28):

I like to think of Controllers as a way to programmatically apply changes in your app that would normally come from user interactions. Controllers are objects you can attach to certain Widgets, and then use those objects to **control** the behaviour of that Widget. Let's look at some examples:

When using a `ListView`, you can attach a `ScrollController` to programmatically interact with the ListView. Maybe you want to scroll the ListView to a certain position when someone presses a button, or you want information about the current offset in your list.

Another similar example is attaching a `PageController` to a `PageView`. Maybe something happens in your app where you want to automatically move to the first page in your PageView. With an attached PageController, you could call `myPageController.animateToPage()` to do that.

A third example is when working with the library for Google Maps, you can attach a `GoogleMapController` and use that to perform all kinds of actions, like moving the map to new coordinates, zooming, rotating, adding markers, etc.

Lastly, to look at one of the examples you gave, when working with a `TextFormField` you can attach a `TextEditingController` to get information about the current value, or perhaps clear the textfield automatically when a "Reset" button is pressed.

When using controllers, the recommended way is to keep them in your state. The code example below is not complete, but hopefully gives you a sense on how to initiate, attach and use a controller, in this case a PageController.

```
class _ControllerDemoState extends State<ControllerDemo> {
  /// Declare the variable to use.
  PageController pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /// Instantiate the PageController in initState.
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  /// When this method is called, we can use the pageController to automatically
  /// animate the PageView to the first page.
  void onButtonPress() {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      0,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
  }

  return PageView(
    /// Attach the controller to the PageView.
    controller: pageController,
    children: [
      ...
    ]
  ),
}
```

Using Controllers properly can be a very powerful way to control the behaviour of your app and is worth learning more about. Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't the code have a dispose() function as well, to prevent memory leak.

Comment: @MarufHassan,as someone new to flutter and just out of curiosity, where is the memory leak in the above code?

Answer (score 13):

A controller can be used to customize the behavior of a widget.
You can pass a custom implementation of a controller.

Sometimes a controller holds state that has a different lifecycle than the widget it is associated with like https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html

Answer (score 1):

`controller` in flutter is a class that perform tasks. These tasks types and nature varies from widget to another depending on what exactly this controller is designed to do.

Examples

> `TextEditingController`
>
> A controller for an editable text field.
>
> Whenever the user modifies a text field with an associated
> TextEditingController, the text field updates value and the controller
> notifies its listeners. Listeners can then read the text and selection
> properties to learn what the user has typed or how the selection has
> been updated.

> `PageController`
>
> A page controller lets you manipulate which page is visible in a
> PageView

> `TabController`
>
> Coordinates tab selection between a TabBar and a TabBarView.
>
> The index property is the index of the selected tab and the animation
> represents the current scroll positions of the tab bar and the tab bar
> view. The selected tab's index can be changed with animateTo.

So listening, taking an action or even coordination could be tasks of a controller serving the view mostly.

Code example that absolutely does not benefits anything from a controller

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// This controller is not useful in anyway
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

An example with controller does an action on user even controlling the animation behaviour as required

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Example', home: FlutterDemo());
  }
}

// Construct Dots Indicator
class FlutterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlutterDemo> createState() => _FlutterDemoState();
}

class _FlutterDemoState extends State<FlutterDemo> {
  // the index of the current page
  int _activePage = 0;

  /// declare and initialize the page controller
  /// with initial page that will show first when create
  /// PageView
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  // this list holds all the pages
  // all of them are constructed in the very end of this file for readability
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const Page(
      color: Colors.pink,
      colorName: 'Pink',
    ),
    const Page(
      color: Colors.blue,
      colorName: 'Blue',
    ),
    const Page(
      color: Colors.green,
      colorName: 'Green',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (int page) {
              setState(() {
                _activePage = page;
              });
            },
            itemCount: _pages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _pages[index % _pages.length];
            },
          ),
          // Display the dots indicator
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            height: 100,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black54,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  _pages.length,
                  (index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _pageController.animateToPage(index,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            curve: Curves.easeIn);
                      },
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 8,
                        // check if a dot is connected to the current page
                        // if true, give it a different color
                        backgroundColor:
                            _activePage == index ? Colors.amber : Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String colorName;

  const Page({Key? key, required this.color, required this.colorName})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: color,
      child: Text(
        '$colorName Page',
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a list of Flutter Controllers documented anywhere.

Comment: Not aware of any official reference. But all controllers I saw this far are extending `ChangeNotifier`. So you might use that as a source to explore implementations.